# How to change the name in the login screen on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts

Immediately after I power my laptop, in Windows 8.1 there is a first screen where I have to enter my password.

I would like to change the name (of the person) to mine. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you googled this problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Open User Accounts by opening Control Panel -> click User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts, and then click Change your account name. (Administrator permission required)
If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.

Type the new name, and then click Change Name. Make sure you restart your computer after this for the changes to come into effect.